# How to create this very specific currency format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have somewhat unusual request to create currency format for displaying values in XLS file (not XLSX) according to the following rules:

1. exactely 3 decimal places
2. decimal separator should be comma
3. thousands separator should be space
4. cell must end with TND

A couple of examples: if I enter 10 it should display 10,000 TND, if I enter 1000 it should display 1 000,000 TND and if I enter 100000 it should display 100 000,000 TND.

I tried various combinations (one example is `###__###__###__##0,000 [$TND]`) but it seems that Excel understands comma as thousands separator and I can't make it to obey to my format. Can anyone give me some pointers what am I doing wrong?

Edit: With the format `####__####__####__###0.000" TND"` I have everything I need **except** comma as decimal separator.

Comment: You can't change decimal separator in number format, it's driven by your regional settings.

Comment: As @MátéJuhász points out, the decimal and thousands separator are determined by your Regional Settings.  You could change them in the `File` ► `Options` ► `Advanced` ► `Editing` ► `Use System Separators`. However, this will change them for **ALL** of your Excel workbooks.  If you do that, then you can simply use `# ###,000" TND"`